# Count in Expression Builder in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Query named Data and it has 5 fields A, B ,C ,D, E. The Field A has always distinct values. I have form with where I have an unbound textBox. Through the Expression Builder for the text box. I use `Count([Data!A])`. When I go to the form view it shows me `#Error`.Where as the count in Query Data is 20. Where am I going wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should read:

```
Count([Data]![A])
```

or just:

```
Count([A])
```

Comment: Perhaps your textbox is named _A_. If so, rename it to, say, _txtA_.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
=DCount("Name_of_your_field";"Name_of_your_table")
```

In your unbound textbox if you don't absolutely need the query.

Comment: Is you form based on your `Data` Query, is it bound to a table or is it an unbound form ?

Comment: It is an Unbound Form. But the Query is Bound to a Table

Comment: See edited Answer. If you need the count of Distinct values of your table field, then it should zork with a DCount instead of a Count

Comment: I already saw you being salty in other posts so I am not even surprised you get offended by this edit.

Get off your high horse, you sent your answer while I was editing mine. Besides, your answer is wrong. OP never mentioned a table with a field called 'a' nor a table called 'data'. But feel free to downgrade edits (this is not agains community rules, is it ?)

Comment: "I have a Query named Data and it has 5 fields A, B ,C ,D, E". There are quite a few minutes difference in edit times. Please quote a post that I have been salty in.

Comment: U are right on the Query name and Field name.
I was using Access and testing the solution myself before providing the answer, thats where the 3 minutes difference between your post and mine come from. I just meant to help OP, not steal any of your fame.
And I don't feel like browsing the ms-access posts to look for your answers. I was just mentioning that I saw u being salty for no reason before, believe it or not.

Comment: You are disingenuous. i  have deleted my answer, does that make you happy?

Comment: So you actually believe I edited my post on purpose after reading your answer ? Oh my. I do believe you know a lot more about MS Access than I do, and I don't even understand why you would think I am being disingenous. I couldn't care less whether you deleted your answer or not: as I said before, I was just trying to help OP. Please keep on being salty for the sake of comedy.

Comment: You really have not read my posts, nor noticed that I almost never answer these days. I only answered this post because both answers were wrong and I only want to help. The reason you cannot discover a salty answer is that there are almost none. Mostly I also help new members like you as well.

Comment: I don't doubt it.
Don't come up with a salty comment in the first place and you will spare yourself and myself 4 or 5 useless comments. Keep on the good work.